# How make bootable usb with Windows XP liveCD from linux (debian)

Tags: windows, linux, usb, boot, livecd

how to create bootable USB with Windows XP liveCD. For Linux liveCD/DVD I can write `cat <debian-iso> > /dev/<flash-drive>`, but in windows case this doesn't works

Comment: What do you want to do? What do work and what doesn't? You talk about USB and flash. USB memory stick are treated as an ordinary USB hard disk. But is it that you call flash? Why use live MS Window CD when it works from a live Linux CD? Easier to just accept that MS Windows are inferior to Linux in this too. Is it not a problem with BIOS?

Comment: I want to create liveUsb from windows xp liveCd iso image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the *many* programs out there designed for exactly this function. Here are a few of my favorites:

- [Live USB multiboot](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/)
- [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Using these apps, you can create a USB that can boot from multiple different ISOs. Including windows.

A great source of information for this kind of thing is the [pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) website.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dd`, not `cat`:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M
```

Where `sdX` is the name of your flash drive. You can find it using `sudo fdisk -l` .

Comment: Not works, Linux sees flash as cdrom, but PC not boots from it

Comment: Could you please explain how linux sees flash as cdrom?