# Ignoree a specific file in file count "wc -l"

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, shell-script, ls

e.g. I have directory like `ABC`. And this directory contain following files (it contain number of files i just include 4 fils here)

```
2014-04-29T06-19-20_17368f93ce.mp4.uploaded
2014-04-29T06-19-20_17368f93ce.mp4
2014-04-29T06-18-20_17368f93ce.mp4
```

I have one `file_name` variable it contain one of the file name that present in the`ABC` directory.

i.e. `file_name=2014-04-29T06-19-20_17368f93ce.mp4`

I am using the following command to find total count of files that ends with only .mp4 in `*ABC*` directory

```
ls -1 /home/ABC/*.mp4 | wc -l
```

So i just want to `ignore`  file in the count that are in the `file_name` variable

Means `file_count` just ignore the file that are in file_name.

Comment: Is this a bash script that you are creating? if so, could you paste in the code. Is the file_name variable an array?

Comment: @user3139907 - Actually I am using shell command in ruby script this is not shell script. this is ruby script, and file_name is the ruby variable

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [never parse the output of `ls`](https://superuser.com/a/533159/151431). Here are some safer approaches:

1. Use `find` and `grep` (`wc -l` fails on filenames that contain newlines):

   ```
   find /home/terdon/foo -not -name "$file_name"  -name '*.mp4' | grep -c /
   ```

   The `-not` flag makes `find` ignore any files called `$file_name`.
2. In this particular case, where your files don't contain whitespace and you probably don't need to deal with portability and language issues, you *can* use `ls`. It is just  a bad habit to get into. So, to use your original approach, just filter out the names you don't want using `grep -v`:

   ```
    ls -1 /home/ABC/*.mp4 | grep -v "$file_name" | wc -l
   ```